# how do i change the value of a dictionary based off of an input?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key-value

beginner programmer here, my apologies-
this is what I am trying to do (plugboard is a dictionary):

```
for x in plugboard:
 
    plugboard[x] = plugboard[x+1]
```

and then print the new version of plugboard. So, I am trying to change the value of each key in the dictionary to the value of the key after it, but i have no idea how to do that. Any help?

(edit)

```
plugboard = {
    'a':'a',
    'b':'b',
    'c':'c',
    'd':'d',
    'e':'e',
    'f':'f',
    'g':'g',
    'h':'h',
    'i':'i',
    'j':'j',
    'k':'k',
    'l':'l',
    'm':'m',
    'n':'n',
    'o':'o',
    'p':'p',
    'q':'q',
    'r':'r',
    's':'s',
    't':'t',
    'u':'u',
    'v':'v',
    'w':'w',
    'x':'x',
    'y':'y',
    'z':'z'
  }
  for x in plugboard:
    plugboard[x] = plugboard[x+1]
  print(plugboard)
```

this is literally the whole program- of course it's part of a larger project, but this is the largest problem I have run into.

Comment: What is supposed to happen for the last one where `x+1` is not in the dict? Is `x` and integer?

Comment: Show us the content of `plugboard` and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: `'a' + 1` doesn't really mean anything — if you walked up to a stranger on a train and asked,  'what's one plus c?', they would think you are crazy. Python also thinks you're crazy. You need to turn those letters into numbers with something like [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#ord) and then you *still* need to decide how to deal with `z`. Maybe something with the `%` modulus operator. Try searching the site for `[python] ceasar cypher` for some ideas.

Comment: that is a very good idea that i absolutely havent thought of- i will try that and come back with any problems, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

`x+1` will raise `TypeError` because `x` (a string) and `1` (an interger) cannot be concatenated to each other. But there are other way to do it, like using [ord(c)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [chr(i)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) which are inverse of one another.

This is one way to implement it:

```
def char_after(char):
    if char == 'z': return 'a'
    return chr(ord(char)+1)

for x in plugboard:
    plugboard[x] = char_after(plugboard[x])
```